# Can websockets substitute HTTP?

Tags: api, http, websocket, background-sync

I am beginning to integrate WebSockets into my app for live updates, and it has lead me to wonder whether I should eliminate HTTP requests from the app altogether.

The downsides I have found so far would be:

1. Harder to split my back-end into MicroServices in the future.
2. Harder to expose an API to third party software in the future.
3. Harder to perform caching and background sync on post requests.

How would I achieve these things with WebSockets?

Also, how reliable is data received through WebSockets? Can I be sure the data is consistent? Can I be sure data I send gets processed correctly? Does it make sense to send "GET" requests through WebSockets?

Opening extra HTTP requests when I have an open WebSocket seems wasteful, but I have so many doubts and questions when it comes to eliminating HTTP.

Comment: You can't really eliminate HTTP completely since WebSocket starts its life as an HTTP(S) request to begin with. Also, WebSocket predates HTTP/2, which has some of the benefits of WebSocket built-in (multi-plexing, server pushes, etc).  So it might be better to upgrade to HTTP/2 than to switch to WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks. I've been doing a lot of research and it seems that a problem with websockets is load balancing and that it drains batteries on phones. Do you know much about that? I have been looking into SSE as well and it seems like a good alternative for my use case. I am annoyed though coz laravel has some great packages to manage websockets and set up your own websocket server with analytics in no time but no support for SSE. Do you know anything about how to handle this in Laravel by any chance? Thanks for your answer.